# Alternative to FormData to keep order of properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3

Uploading to Amazon S3 requires keeping a specific order in your form's data. For instance, I currently have something that looks like this:

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('acl', 'acl here');
  formData.append('key', 'key here');
  formData.append('file', "file goes here e.g. $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]");
```

And then a typical ajax call.

Is there an alternative to FormData which would definitely keep the order of the properties? In this case, 'acl' should be first, 'key' second, 'file' last.

Looking for an alternative because according to caniuse.com, 8% of the global traffic does not support FormData.

The only alternative way that I can think of is to have an HTML form, fill the fields dynamically with JavaScript (they are not known on page load), and then submit the form via jQuery form's ajaxSubmit (to have the percent progress). I'd like to avoid the need of having an HTML form and using jQuery form though.

Whole code:

```
    // TODO: Find alternative to FormData, keeping a 100% JS-solution (only library: jQuery)
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('acl','acl');
    formData.append('key', 'key');
    formData.append('file', $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://MyLittleBucket.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com',
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                }
            };

            return xhr;
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log('File uploaded');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Upload error');
        }
    });
```

Note: There is a file input in the HTML and I look for the "change" event in JS, and then proceed to the above upload.

Comment: It's unclear what your asking. I understand that you want an alternative to `formData`, but you obviously already have an HTML form if the user is uploading files.

Comment: No form. Only a file input. Detecting the file on "change" event and then proceeding to the upload. Trying to spare unnecessary details though.